# Update dataframe column to another dataframe's column on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have 2 dataframes:

```
#DF1

   1  2  3  4  5
0  A  B  C  D  E
1  D  A  B  K  J
2  B  D  A  A  A
3  C  A  B  K  J

and

#DF2

  ID  SUB_VALUE
0  B  REPLACE_X
1  C  REPLACE_Y
```

I want to update all the record values in column 1 (DF1), if that value is present in the ID column of DF2. The updated value should be the corresponding SUB_VALUE of DF2.

So the results should look like this:

```
           1  2  3  4  5
0          A  B  C  D  E
1          D  A  B  K  J
2  REPLACE_X  D  A  A  A
3  REPLACE_y  A  B  K  J
```

(Because B and C from column 1 are present in the second df, and the corresponding sub_values are REPLACE_X AND REPLACE_Y.)

What I tried:

```
#creating datasets
keys = {"B": "REPLACE_X",
        "C": "REPLACE_Y"}
helper_df = pd.DataFrame(keys.items(), columns=["ID", "SUB_VALUE"])

df_lst = [["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
          ["D", "A", "B", "K", "J"],
          ["B", "D", "A", "A", "A"],
          ["C", "A", "B", "K", "J"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_lst,
                  columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

#creating mask for filtering
m = (df["1"].isin(helper_df["ID"].tolist()))
df.loc[m, "1"] = #and here is where I have no idea how to find the corresponding value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using mask, to update only if the value is present in the helper_df

```
df['1'] = df['1'].mask(
    (df['1'].map(helper_df.set_index(['ID'])['SUB_VALUE'])).notna(),
    (df['1'].map(helper_df.set_index(['ID'])['SUB_VALUE']))
)
df
```

```
1   2   3   4   5
0   A   B   C   D   E
1   D   A   B   K   J
2   REPLACE_X   D   A   A   A
3   REPLACE_Y   A   B   K   J
```

Comment: I'll be able to in a minute. Just one more question. If I have another conditions, not just that the value should be present in the other dataframe's column, but for example the value to be "B". How would you implement that? In that case only the index 2 would be replaced.

Comment: I'm not quiet following you. if you meant, some additional condition to be evaluated to TRUE prior to mapping? Then yes, you can just make the condition as a compound condition

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe the following line should make the job

```py
df["1"] = df["1"].replace(helper_df.set_index('ID').to_dict()["SUB_VALUE"])
```

output

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   A   B   C   D   E
1   D   A   B   K   J
2   REPLACE_X   D   A   A   A
3   REPLACE_Y   A   B   K   J
```

if you have your values already in a dcitionary you can directly do

```py
keys = {"B": "REPLACE_X",
        "C": "REPLACE_Y"}
df["1"] = df["1"].replace(keys)
```

Comment: that is close, but this actually makes the values which are not present in the dictionary to NAN

Comment: using repalce instead of map works!